# test yaml-cpp 0.5.3 issue

Tags: yaml, yaml-cpp

I am tried to know about yaml rules.
 And **init.yaml** file is like this:

```
name: Ryan Braun
position: LF
```

Main code:

```
int main()
{
    YAML::Node node = YAML::LoadFile("init.yaml");
    cout << node.Type() << endl;
   return 0;
}
```

This was just a simple example, I want to see my node's type. This should a map as described in [How To Emit YAML](https://github.com/jbeder/yaml-cpp/wiki/How-To-Emit-YAML). But the output is 0, which means is **Undefined**. That makes me confused. Maybe I misunderstand.
Any suggestions will be thankful.

Comment: Does it work when you do this instead: `YAML::Load("name: Ryan Braun\nposition: LF");` ?

Comment: @flyx, I got **what():  yaml-cpp: error at line 0, column 0: bad file** tried with your suggestion.

Comment: This hints to some serious problem with yaml-cpp in your environment, as loading a string should definitely work and the fact that it gives a *bad file* error shows that something very strange is going on. Unfortunately, I have not enough knowledge about yaml-cpp to help you at this point.